# Embedding extension of sheaves in direct sum

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g\geq2$, we can construct rank $2$ vector bundles on $X$ with determinant $\omega_X$ by extension $$0\to \mathcal{O}\to E\to\omega_X\to 0,$$ does such $E$ necessarily embeds in $\omega_X\oplus\omega_X$? (for general $E$?)

Comment: No, it doesn't. For a general such extension, $h^0(E)=h^1(E)=1$. Therefore $h^0(\mathscr{H}om(E,\omega _X)=k$, and there is only one way (up to a scalar) to map $E$ to $\omega _X$.

Comment: @abx Thanks! Is there a reason why $h^0(E)=1$ for a general extension?

Comment: On the moduli space of rank 2 vector bundles with $\det=\omega _X$ those with $h^0>0$ form the so-called Theta divisor. It is well-known that a general element has $h^0=1$.

Comment: @abx Thanks! But I am not quite sure if a 'general extension' necessarily a 'general s.s. vector bundle with $h^0>0$'? (If we take $Hom(\mathcal{O},-)$, then we are just asking if $[E]\colon H^0(\omega_X)\to H^1(\mathcal{O})$ an isomorphism, could there be a direct reason?)

Comment: Yes. For $\alpha \neq 0$ in $H^0(\omega _X)$, the kernel of $\times \alpha :H^1(\omega _X^{-1})\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ has codimension $g$. As the family of these kernels has dimension $g-1$, they do not fill 
$H^1(\omega _X^{-1})$.

Comment: @abx Why don't you consolidate your comments into an answer?

Comment: @abx Thanks! I think the $\times\alpha$ is surjective, because every 1-cycle $\{U_{ij}\to f_{ij}\}$ has  $\{U_{ij}\mapsto f_{ij}/\alpha\}$ as inverse image? or is there a better way to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let me merge my comments into an answer. I claim that for a general extension $0\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X\rightarrow E\rightarrow \omega _X\rightarrow 0$, we have $h^0(E)=1$; therefore $h^0(\mathscr{H}om(E,\omega _X))=1$ by Riemann-Roch and Serre duality, so  there is only one way (up to a scalar) to map $E$ to $\omega _X$.

The claim follows from a linear algebra lemma:

**Lemma**$.-$ *Let $b:V\times W\rightarrow U$ be a bilinear map between vector spaces, with $\dim V\leq \dim U$ and $b(v,-): W\rightarrow U$ surjective for each $v\neq 0$ in $V$. Then $b(-,w): V\rightarrow U$ is injective for $w$ general in $W$*.

*Proof* : For $v\neq 0$ in $V$, the kernel of $b(v,-)$ has codimension $\dim U$. These kernels are parameterized by $\mathbb{P}(V)$, of dimension $\dim V-1\leq \dim U-1$, and therefore they do not fill $W$. So for $w\in W$ general $b(v,w)=0$ implies $v=0$.

Now we apply the lemma with $V=H^0(\omega _X)$, $W= \operatorname{Ext}^1(\omega _X,\mathscr{O}_X)\cong H^1(\omega _X^{-1}) $, $U=H^1(\mathscr{O}_X)$. We must check that $\times \,\alpha : H^1(\omega _X^{-1}) \rightarrow H^1(\mathscr{O}_X)$ is surjective for $\alpha \neq 0$ in $H^0(\omega _X)$. This follows from the exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \omega _X^{-1}\xrightarrow{\ \alpha \ }\mathscr{O}_X\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_Z\rightarrow 0$$
with $Z=\operatorname{div}(\alpha ) $, and from $H^1(\mathscr{O}_Z)=0$.